# CSS Animation Not Working when Added via JavaScript

Tags: css

I have a web page that is using Bootstrap 5. This web page has one element stacked on top of another. After a period of time, I'm trying to fade-out the top element. In an attempt to do this, I have:

**HTML**

```
<div id="host" class="position-relative">
  <div id="content" class="position-absolute top-0 left-0 w-100"></div>
  <div id="curtain" class="position-relative top-0 left-0 h-100 opacity-100" style="background-color: orange; z-index:1000;">
        Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
    from { opacity: 1; }  
    to { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
    from { opacity: 1; }  
    to { opacity: 0; }
}

.fade-out {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: fade-out;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

The other css class are from Bootstrap 5.

This layout works like I want (i.e. the "Loading" is on top of the content). However, the "curtain" doesn't fade out. In an attempt to make it fade out, I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('here');
    var curtain = document.getElementById('curtain');
    curtain.classList.add('fade-out');
  }, 5000);
</script>
```

The timeout behaves as expected. I've confirmed in Chrome that the `fade-out` class is getting added to my element. However, the animation is not occurring. What is wrong with my CSS animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code you can add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;`
so your animation doesn't reset

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  var curtain = document.getElementById('curtain');
  curtain.classList.add('fade-out');
}, 3000);
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fade-out {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade-out;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: fade-out;
  animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="host" class="position-relative">
  <div id="content" class="position-absolute top-0 left-0 w-100"></div>
  <div id="curtain" class="position-relative top-0 left-0 h-100 opacity-100" style="background-color: orange; z-index:1000;">
    Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If want `animation` to remain in its last state use `forwards` in short hand property

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  alert('here');
  var curtain = document.getElementById('curtain');
  curtain.classList.add('fade-out');
}, 5000);
```

```css
.fade-out-class {
  animation: fade-out 3s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.fade-out {
-webkit-animation:  fade-out 5s forwards; 
  animation: fade-out 5s forwards;
}

#curtain {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 5vw;
  width: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="host" class="position-relative">
  <div id="content" class="position-absolute top-0 left-0 w-100">You can't see me before as I was under curtain</div>
  <div id="curtain" class="position-relative top-0 left-0 h-100 opacity-100" style="background-color: orange; z-index:1000;">
    Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```